# Receiving a Duplicate Entry Error when using REPLACE INTO

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `REPLACE INTO SELECT...` statement but I am receiving `Duplicate Entry 'XXXX' for key 'PRIMARY'`. I thought the whole purpose of REPLACE INTO was to delete the record if it already exists. How is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the value you are inserting conflicts with *another* row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry so are you saying that it's if there are 2 duplicate rows with different PKs in the table already? I checked and there don't seem to be

Comment: Don't forget the error could be coming from a trigger(s) if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `SELECT` on your table first to see how many instances there are of that row.

You may find that there is already duplicates within your table, in which case you may need to delete some rows.

Comment: I did try to do that and there are some similar rows but none of them are exact duplicates...